# How to print elements of a linked list without using head

Tags: java, list, nodes

I am trying to rewrite this program without using the head node, any help?

I've tried the `getFirst()` method to set the pointer to the first element of the linked list, it did not work. Is there any way I can set the first value of the linked list to be the new head without actually creating a head with value `0`?

```
class Node {


int value;
    Node next;

    public Node(int v) {   //gives the node a value
        value = v;
    }
}


public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

        int[] array = {1, 2, 5, 3, 0, 8};
        Node head = new Node(0);
        Node current = head;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            // 2. create each node object
            Node node = new Node(array[i]);
            current.next = node;  
            current = node; 
        }

        current = head.next; 
        while (current != null) {  
            System.out.println(current.value);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not read the first element from `array` and put that into `new Node`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just **initialize Head with first element of array.**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

        int[] array = {1, 2, 5, 3, 0, 8};

        // Initialize head with first element of array. 
        Node head = new Node(array[0]);
        Node current = head;

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            // 2. create each node object
            Node node = new Node(array[i]);
            current.next = node;  
            current = node; 
        }

        current = head; 
        while (current != null) {  
            System.out.println(current.value);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  initialise your head in the first iteration. Here's a simple code for you:

```
class Node {
    int value;
    Node next;

    public Node(int v) {   //gives the node a value
        value = v;
    }
}


class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

        int[] array = {1, 2, 5, 3, 0, 8};
        Node head = null, current = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(head == null){
                head = new Node(array[i]);
                current = head;
            }
            else{
                current.next = new Node(array[i]);
                current = current.next;
            }
        }

        current = head; 
        while (current != null) {  
            System.out.println(current.value);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

I strongly recommend you to follow some course on algorithms and data structures to strengthen your basics. Here's a good start: [Codemonk](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/codemonk/)